# How to log in to multiplayer Minecraft without an account?

Tags: minecraft-bedrock-edition, ps4

I'm trying to play PS4 standard Minecraft on multiplayer, but can never connect as I keep getting "unable to connect to world" error.

Now the only reason I can think of for this is that I am not logged into my Microsoft account since it's impossible, because the email for that account got deleted and I forgot the password. I tried setting up another account, but then I get "oops unable to connect, try logging in to your previously connected account". I assume it is referring to the account I've told you about.

What should I do? It's like Microsoft is saying "Oh, seems you found another way to enjoy a game you actually paid for. Not on my watch!".

Comment: Welcome to Arqade! This looks like a Microsoft support problem, I don't think we can do anything to help you

Answer (score 1):

You cannot join multiplayer worlds without being in an account. If you havn't already tried you can [submit a help request to Microsoft](https://help.minecraft.net/hc/en-us/requests/new) to try to get your account back, but you'll probably have to get proof you owned the account.